# AngularJS Ng Repeat remove "," after the Last Word inside Loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Angular Js Ng Repeat remove "," after the Last Word inside Loop
I have Tried with $last but I am filtering with selected = true condition on the array.

```
<span ng-repeat="primaryPrograms in ctrl.primaryProgramStudies" ng-show="primaryPrograms.selected == true">
    {{primaryPrograms.name}} , 
</span>
```

Output : `ACT , AP , Math(non-SAT) ,`

**With Index:**

I have to Get only selected =true values from the loop

```
<span ng-repeat="primaryPrograms in ctrl.primaryProgramStudies track by $index" ng-show="primaryPrograms.selected == true"> 
        {{$index}}  - {{primaryPrograms.name}} <span ng-if="!$last">, </span>
</span>
```

1 - ACT , 4 - AP , 7 - Math(non-SAT) ,

I want to Remove, after the last Word. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ng-if="!$last"` to remove last comma(,)

Code:

```
<span ng-repeat="primaryPrograms in ctrl.primaryProgramStudies track by $index" ng-show="primaryPrograms.selected == true">
    {{primaryPrograms.name}} <span ng-if="!$last">, </span>
</span>
```

Edit\Updated:

You can use `filter` for same because you have the extra `ng-show` condition there, (after filter remove `ng-show`)

```
 <div ng-repeat="primaryPrograms in ctrl.primaryProgramStudies | filter: {selected  : true} track by $index">
    <span>{{primaryPrograms.name}}</span><span ng-if="!$last">,</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: with last the id's are not coming Properly because I have added if conditions to it. [added your script to question with output]

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

try below code , you can hide "," if $index is last value

```
<span ng-repeat="primaryPrograms in ctrl.primaryProgramStudies" ng-show="primaryPrograms.selected == true">
{{primaryPrograms.name}} <span ng-hide="$index==ctrl.primaryProgramStudies.length-1">,</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <span ng-repeat="primaryPrograms in ctrl.primaryProgramStudies" ng-show="primaryPrograms.selected == true">
   {{primaryPrograms.name + (!$last ? ',':'')}} 
</span>
```

Comment: can you Refer the Updated Question.

Answer (score -1):

Try

> ng-if="$index!=0"

```
<span ng-repeat="primaryPrograms in ctrl.primaryProgramStudies" ng-show="primaryPrograms.selected == true">
    <i ng-if="$index!=0">,</i>{{primaryPrograms.name}} 
</span>
```

Comment: all commas coming before letters `,1 ACT ,4 AP ,7 Math(non-SAT)`

Comment: there are another condition if you can see `ng-show="primaryPrograms.selected == true"` in question

Comment: any Idea about adding this condition to Loop to get proper index. .?